# Some substitution words for "up in the air"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

"Up in the air" is not formal in academic writing.

Can anyone provide me another word (as clean as possible, don't use another idiom) which has the same meaning?

Comment: So, I won't offer " all at sea", "at sixes and sevens", ... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncertain
 Not yet decided. / [yet] to be decided (TBD)
 Not finalised.
 Subject to review.
 An interim decision is ...
Subject to uncertainty.
Indeterminate
Not statistically significant.
 Ill conditioned.
 As yet unknown.
 Not knowable given available information.
Is expected to be come clearer as things progress / more data becomes available  / the situation develops ...

**:-):**
Who can know these things???

It is not ours to know. Yah?

You can use many variants of some of these.

Not finalised
 Not yet finalised.
 Still unfinalised.
 Will be finalised
 As yet not finalised.
...

Comment: My first thought was "undecided", but variations on "uncertain" are also good.

Answer (score 1):

Uncertain, ambiguous, doubtful, unpredictable, indeterminate, changeable are some of the words you can substitute for the idiom **Up in the air**.

Answer (score 1):

•  *[tentative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tentative#Adjective)*, “Of or pertaining to a trial or trials; ... experimental” or “Uncertain; subject to future change”
•  *[probationary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/probationary#Adjective)* (“subject to probation”), or  *[probation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/probation#Noun)*, a period of time when something is conditional),
•  *[transitional](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transitional#Adjective)*, “temporary; pending the implementation of something new”
• *[pro tem](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pro_tem#Adverb)*, “temporarily; for the time being” (as adverb) or, as an adjective, temporary
• *[provisional](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/provisional)*, temporary, or temporary and conditional, or “by way of provision for the time being”